# The same destination regardless of origin

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

When I was very little, I didn’t understand some basics of the space we live in. We always followed the same directions to get into town, to school, to the grocery store, and so on. So I figured that by following those directions, we would always arrive at the same destination *no matter where we left from*. It only happened that we always left from home.

In other words, I assumed space was more like a fully-connected graph than the continuous 3-space it seems to be. Vertices were places, and edges were the mystical “directions” by which you could travel between places. This hypothesis didn’t exactly stand up to experimentation. However I am curious to know two things:

1. Suppose a directed graph where outgoing edges are numbered; what does the set of graphs look like where any given path, say, as a list of edge numbers, has a constant destination?
2. Does a (nontrivial) continuous space or surface exist where any given translation $T$ has a constant destination?

Examples:

- A directed graph with one vertex connected to itself.
- A directed graph with $kn+1$ vertices: a central self-connected vertex and $k$ “spokes” of length $n$.
- A continuous 0-space.

Comment: In your $kn+1$ example, doesn't the central vertex also need an edge connecting it to itself? Also what is a continuous $0$-space?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Right you are; edited. The 0-space was a joke—no moves are possible, so every one of the 0 allowable moves will take you to the same place, for any of the 0 available starting locations you care to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking question 2. with a fairly liberal (and admittedly naive)  interpretation, we could always consider a vector field $F$ with a single attractive fixed point - e.g. $F(\mathbf{x})=y\hat{\imath}-(x+y)\hat{\jmath}$, which has a spiral sink at $\mathbf{x}=(0,0)$.   Then, the family of solutions to the differential equation

$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}=F(\mathbf{x})
$$ for varying initial conditions $\mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf{x}_0$, defines a continuous space where "all objects have a common destination regardless of origin," the desination being the fixed point $(0,0)$.  Below is a PPlane output for a few trajectories:

[image]

This could probably, of course, be generalized a great deal by an expert in dynamical systems (which I don't really claim to be).

Comment: This isn’t quite what I was getting at. I meant, supposing a path constitutes a function from locations to locations, then every path is a constant function. Though that is true, in a sense, of systems where there is only one possible destination.